# How to read the error when writing vector files in QGIS 3.0

Tags: qgis-3, pyqgis-3

Upgraded to QGIS 3.0 and now I cant read writer errors. The following (post 2to3) code doesnt print the error to the console:

```py
CRS=QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem().fromEpsgId(4326)
error = QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(vl,fp, "system", CRS, "ESRI Shapefile")
if QgsVectorFileWriter.hasError(error):
    print("uh oh an error")
    print(QgsVectorFileWriter.errorMessage(error))
```

rather than reporting the error I get:

`TypeError: QgsVectorFileWriter.hasError(): first argument of unbound method must have type 'QgsVectorFileWriter'`

How can I modify this so that the write error is reported?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at the [API Documentation](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsVectorFileWriter.html?highlight=qgsvectorfilewriter#qgis.core.QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat) which mentions the following signature for this method:

> `writeAsVectorFormat(layer: QgsVectorLayer, fileName: str, fileEncoding: str, destCRS: QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(), driverName: str = '', onlySelected: bool = False, datasourceOptions: Iterable[str] = [], layerOptions: Iterable[str] = [], skipAttributeCreation: bool = False, newFilename: str = '', symbologyExport: QgsVectorFileWriter.SymbologyExport = QgsVectorFileWriter.NoSymbology, symbologyScale: float = 1, filterExtent: QgsRectangle = None, overrideGeometryType: QgsWkbTypes.Type = QgsWkbTypes.Unknown, forceMulti: bool = False, includeZ: bool = False, attributes: Iterable[int] = [], fieldValueConverter: QgsVectorFileWriter.FieldValueConverter = None) → Tuple[QgsVectorFileWriter.WriterError, str]`

The last part is interesting here, it's the return value: `→ Tuple[QgsVectorFileWriter.WriterError, str]`

Tuples can be read like this:

```py
error, error_string = QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(....)
```

so you probably want to use something like this

```py
error, error_string = QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(....)
if error != QgsVectorFileWriter.NoError:
    print('Oh an error has happened: {details}'.format(details=error_string))
```

Comment: Nice, here's hoping that tuple info makes it into the pyqgis cookbook which is still very much about 2.x. For some of us the api docs are rather opaque and a solid working example is a much faster way forward. Cheers.

Comment: If I run this line:
writer = QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(arguments etc..), my returned writer tuple is  (8, ''). In other words, a blank error string. How do I use that?